# Why are Python's datetime ISO-functions logically incorrect and buggy?

Tags: python, iso8601

I'm kind of stunned that the python `datetime` `.isoformat()` function doesn't return correct information.  The function correctly returns an ISO 8601-formatted string when a timezone is provided to the fromtimestamp() method. However, the timezone is ignored in the calculation of the resultant. Observe:

```
13:29 msimsonnet:~$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jan 26 2011, 13:56:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Running with pythonstartup.py
>>> import pytz,datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1303876413).isoformat()
'2011-04-26T23:53:33'
>>> ny = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
>>> sf = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1303876413,ny).isoformat()
'2011-04-26T23:53:33-04:00'
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1303876413,sf).isoformat()
'2011-04-26T20:53:33-07:00'
>>>
```

I'm running this on a computer that's in EDT (-400 from GMT). The time 1303876413 is actually 11:53:33pm on April 26, 2011, when I first wrote the question. Notice that in the first example simply requesting `.isoformat()` returns `'2011-04-26T23:53:33'`, which is wrong --- it should return `'2011-04-26T23:53:33-04:00'`, since it's returning local time and Python knows the timezone. The second example is correct, but I am jamming in the NY timezone object. The third example is just wrong --- Python is preserving the timezone, but it's not adjusting the time accordingly.

ADDENDUM:

If you read all of the comments, you'll see that the behavior I was looking for can be found using `utcfromtimestamp` rather than `fromtimestamp`

Comment: No reason for the downvote here, it's an excellent question (If a tad emotive...)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure you are using "timezone aware" `datetime` objects, not "naive" objects.

In order to make a timezone "aware" `datetime` object you need to be sure to provide the timezone when you create it.

More details are here:
http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Also, ISO 8601 does *not* require timezone, and `isoformat` *is* compliant.  In fact, it doesn't support timezone at all, only time *offsets* from UTC.

ISO 8601 allows many different formats, for example, these are all valid:

```
2011-04-27
2011-04-27 02:48Z
2011-04-27T02:48Z
2011-W17-3
2011-117
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 for more details.

**Edit, to address your updates:**

It's not buggy, it works properly, and according to the docs.  Naive datetime objects just don't have any time zone information, period.  So there's no reason to expect that they'd be able to give you timezone information when you call `isoformat()`.

When you create an object using the timestamp, it makes a local time datetime object based on whatever python thinks your system time zone is.   That's why when you give it a posix timestamp, it converts it to your local time for you.   Note that while the datetime module knows that a timestamp is UTC, and it knows your local time zone, and `fromtimestamp` uses that information to create a datetime object, the resulting object is still naive and doesn't anything about time zones.  If you want to use timestamps, you shouldn't use naive datetime objects.

From the docs:

> Whether a naive datetime object
>   represents Coordinated Universal Time
>   (UTC), local time, or time in some
>   other timezone is purely up to the
>   program, just like it’s up to the
>   program whether a particular number
>   represents metres, miles, or mass.
>   Naive datetime objects are easy to
>   understand and to work with, at the
>   cost of ignoring some aspects of
>   reality.

Here is the documentation for the `fromtimestamp` method (bolding added):

> Return the local date and time
>   corresponding to the POSIX timestamp,
>   such as is returned by time.time(). **If
>   optional argument tz is None or not
>   specified, the timestamp is converted
>   to the platform’s local date and time,
>   and the returned datetime object is
>   naive.**

**If you want it to consider time zone, you need to pass a time zone, it won't infer it for you.**  Just because it doesn't do what you think it should do does not make it non-compliant or buggy.  It works as intended, and as is documented.  That's pretty much the opposite of buggy.

Comment: The wikipedia page says "There are no time zone designators in ISO 8601. Time is only represented as local time or in relation to UTC."

Comment: I thought that's what I said... "...in relation to UTC"

Comment: Shouldn't the fromtimestamp() method automatically put the datatime into GMT (Z), since all Unix timestamps are relative to GMT?

Comment: I have substantially reworked the example so that you can now see how buggy Python is.

Comment: @TM, THanks for your response. However, I think that you misunderstand my concern here. Unix timestamps are the number of seconds from January 1, 1970, and exist independent of timezone. So it makes no logical sense for the `frometimestamp` method to create a datetime without a timezone. If a timezone is specified, the resultant datetime object should be in that timezone. The current behavior results in different absolute times for the same unix timestamp depending on the TZ object that's passed in, and that's incorrect behavior. It may be what the docs say, but the behavior is wrong.

Comment: "the resultant datetime object should be in that timezone"  It's not in ANY timezone, that's the point you are missing.  It is timezone UNAWARE.   It's just a date and time of day, that's all.   `fromtimestamp` assumes that you want things in your local system time (most apps would want this, since usually you want to see things in your local time).  If you want them in a different time zone, then you can pass the `tz` arg.

Comment: @TM, When you change the timezone that's passed to `fromtimestamp`, the resultant datetime object has a different timezone but the same date and time values.  That makes no sense.  I agree with you that `fromtimestamp` is assuming you want local system time. It properly should put in the timezone. However, it shouldn't construct a wrong value when a different timezone is provided. The implementation appears to be always doing a local timezone conversion and then just carrying through the provided TZ, which is wrong.

Comment: @vy32 It's timezone unaware.  It's not carrying through any timezone.  Not sure what else I can say to explain it :/   Good luck.

Comment: Apparently I should ahve been using `utcfromtimestamp` and not `fromtimestamp`